# How can I listen to the scroll event in a sidebar [Bootstrap Vue]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using the [Sidebar](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/sidebar) component from BootstrapVue to render a navigation for my application.

As an example, I have 30 menu items in my navigation, so the content within the sidebar scrolls vertically. I would like to bind to that scroll event to dynamiclly add/remove some classes.

I have tried to create a custom scroll directive:

```
Vue.directive('scroll', {
    inserted: function(el, binding) {
        console.log('el', el);
        let f = function(evt) {
            if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', f);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
    }
});
```

...then register that to the component within my vue file:

```
<b-sidebar
   v-scroll="handleScroll"
   title="Menu"
   shadow="lg"
   backdrop
   @change="$emit('sidebar-change')"


...

handleScroll() {
      console.log('handleScroll');
},
```

The directive is being picked up properly, but my `handleScroll` method is firing when the main body is scrolling, not the sidebar.

In my directive, I am logging to see what element it thinks it's working with:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="b-sidebar-outer">...</div>
```

Since Bootstrap is dynamiclly creating the markup for the overlay, that's the parent element -- looking closer, I believe I need to attach my directive to this:

```
<div class="b-sidebar-body">...</div>
```

That is the `<div>` that looks to be scrolling. However, since it is generated at runtime, I don't know how to hook into that.

I have also tried using `@native.scroll="myMethod"` on the component...no luck there either.

How can I listen for the scroll event *within* my sidebar component? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scroll` listener fires on the main window because the directive attached the event listener to `window`, and not the element.

To listen to scroll events on the contents of `b-sidebar`, the listener should be on an element inside the default slot of `b-sidebar` (not the `b-sidebar`  itself).

1. Put a wrapper `div` inside `b-sidebar`'s default slot, and style it to enable scrolling:

   ```html
   <template>
     <b-sidebar>
       <div class="wrapper">
         <!-- your actual contents here -->
       </div>
     </b-sidebar>
   </template>

   <style>
   .wrapper {
     overflow: auto;
     height: 100%;
   }
   </style>
   ```
2. Add the custom `v-scroll` directive on the wrapper `div`:

   ```html
   <div class="wrapper" v-scroll="handleScroll">
   ```
3. Update the custom directive to add the binding value as the event listener on the given element's `scroll` event:

   ```js
   Vue.directive('scroll', (el, binding) => {
     let f = (evt) => {
       if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
         el.removeEventListener('scroll', f)
       }
     }

     el.addEventListener('scroll', f)
   })
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wvJYPqR?editors=1111)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It really gave me the push I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the event's target is the sidebar and only execute your function if it is.